# react redux problem with a promise, because my variable is null

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React-Redux app and I have a problem with promise. For the started, I would like to give you my code:

the problem is that my dateApi is just 'surprising' the second time. I need to make a promise, but I do not know how to do it.

PROBLEM: this is my method in react front-end:

```
...
    this.props.handleLastWeek(this.props.dateFrom, this.props.dateTo);
    // ^^ this returns dataApi ^^

    var i = 1;
    var j = 1;
    var k = 1;
    var l = 0;
    var dateArray = [];
    this.props.dataApi.map(dA => {
    ... // this.props.dataApi is null
```

Reducer:

```
case GET_DATA_LAST_WEEK:
  return state.set("dataApi", []).set("isLoading", true);

case GET_DATA_LAST_WEEK_SUCCESS:
  return state.set("isLoading", false).set("dataApi", action.response);
```

This is my actions: (response is my dataApi)

```
export function getDataLastWeekAction(from, to) {
  return {
    type: GET_DATA_LAST_WEEK,
    from,
    to
  };
}

export function successDataLastWeekAction(response) {
  return {
    type: GET_DATA_LAST_WEEK_SUCCESS,
    response
  };
}
```

And this is my redux-saga function:

```
    export function* handleLastWeek() {
  const from = yield select(makeSelectDateFrom());
  const to = yield select(makeSelectDateTo());
  const requestURL = `/api/daydate`;

  try {
    const response = yield call(request, requestURL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        from,
        to
      })
    });

    if (response) {
      yield put(successDataLastWeekAction(response));
    } else {
      yield put(errorDataLastWeekAction("Spróbuj ponownie za moment."));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(errorDataLastWeekAction(err));
  }
}
```

Comment: where is `this.props.dataApi.map(dA => { ... // this.props.dataApi is null` called? from the render()?

Comment: @TyroHunter, in componentDidMount() but not only. I use this in onClick function etc.

Comment: can you log the response like below just to make sure your api is really responding the expected data:

`console.log(response);
if (response) {
      yield put(successDataLastWeekAction(response));
    } else {
      yield put(errorDataLastWeekAction("Spróbuj ponownie za moment."));
    }`

If you see the data logged then the problem might not be related to promise, but to your redux connections

Comment: @Tyro, yes. API always return true data and this problem is in promise 100%

Comment: ok then try `console.log(this.props.dataApi)` this time on the render method, it should be called at least twice, and compare the two logs, do you see the expected data from the second log (2nd call of render)?

Comment: @TyroHunter, yes. first console.log is empty array, and secounds console is is my true array with data

Comment: So I hope you have a hint now? just to explain further: render was called again after you dispatch from redux. Refer to `if (response) {
      yield put(successDataLastWeekAction(response));
    }` This is the normal behavior of containers or component that are connected to redux state. It is able to listen or update itself when the state changes, thus re-render.

So if I were you, you would create a "render method" maybe renderData() { return ....map(data => <div>{data.field1}</div> } so now your render method will look like this:
`render() {
return <div>{this.renderData()}<div>
}`